# cmake_parse_arguments storing empty strings

Tags: cmake, arguments, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use the function signature variation of [`cmake_parse_arguments()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html#cmake-parse-arguments), mirroring the example for macros:

```cmake
include(CMakeParseArguments)

set(prefix PREFIX_)
set(${prefix}VAR "foo")
message(DEBUG " value of " "${prefix}VAR" " is " ${${prefix}VAR})

function(func)
    set(prefix ARG_)
    set(options OPTION)
    set(oneValueArgs VALUE)
    set(multiValueArgs MULTIVALUE)
    cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 "${prefix}" "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}")

    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}OPTION})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}VALUE})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}MULTIVALUE})
endfunction(func)

func(VALUE 42 MULTIVALUE "foo" "bar" "baz")
```

The message output is:

```
DEBUG value of PREFIX_VAR is foo
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG
```

The output is only empty strings. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`cmake_parse_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html#cmake-parse-arguments):

> `cmake_parse_arguments` will consider for each of the keywords listed in `<options>`, `<one_value_keywords>` and `<multi_value_keywords>` a variable composed of the given `<prefix>` followed by `"_"` and the name of the respective keyword.

For example, one of the variables populated after running this method is `<prefix>_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS`. Because your prefix ***already*** contains an underscore, it gets expanded to `ARG__UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS` (with two underscores after `ARG`). Thus, adding the extra underscore to your `message()` calls yields the parsed values:

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)

set(prefix PREFIX_)
set(${prefix}VAR "foo")
message(DEBUG " value of " "${prefix}VAR" " is " ${${prefix}VAR})

function(func)
    set(prefix ARG_)
    set(options OPTION)
    set(oneValueArgs VALUE)
    set(multiValueArgs MULTIVALUE)
    cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 "${prefix}" "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}")

    # Add additional underscore to the variables expanded here!
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}_OPTION})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}_VALUE})
    message(DEBUG ${${prefix}_MULTIVALUE})
endfunction(func)

func(VALUE 42 MULTIVALUE "foo" "bar" "baz")
```

This prints the following:

```
DEBUG value of PREFIX_VAR is foo
DEBUG
DEBUG FALSE
DEBUG 42
DEBUG foobarbaz
```